# elpy flymake does not recognize local .pylintrc

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, projectile, elpy, directory-local-variables

I have the following in the project root for my .pylintrc:

```
[FORMAT]

# Maximum number of characters on a single line.
max-line-length=1000

# String used as indentation unit. This is usually "    " (4 spaces) or "\t" (1
# tab).
# Use 2 spaces consistent with TensorFlow style.
indent-string='  '
```

I am using `elpy` and while I see my syntax checker is correctly recognized as my project's `flake8` binary within its environment, the `.pylintrc` is not being picked up, with the result that long lines and indents are still being highlighted.

How can I tell elpy/flymake/flake8/flycheck to recognize my directory local .pylintrc in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I remember having this issue once. Turn out my `flycheck-flake8rc` value is ".flake8rc", not ".flake8". Not sure if this applies to you.

---

Original:

<strike>According to the OP, you are using `flake8` as your checker, but you are setting `.pylintrc` which is the config file for `pylint`. I've never used pylint, so I might be wrong about this one. But according to `flake8` [documentation](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html), it doesn't mention anything about `.pylintrc`:</strike>

> Flake8 supports storing its configuration in the following places:
>
> - Your top-level user directory
> - In your project in one of `setup.cfg`, `tox.ini`, or `.flake8`.
>
> Values set at the command line have highest priority, then those in the project configuration file, then those in your user directory, and finally there are the defaults. However, there are additional command line options which can alter this.

Comment: I also have a .flake8 file that includes `[flake8]
ignore = E111` but I still see it flagging that the indentation is not a multiple of 4.  So it isn't recognizing my .flake8 either.

Comment: Oh, I remember having similar issue. What is the value in `C-h v` for variable `flycheck-flake8rc` ?

Comment: I think some variation of this, naming stuff, is actually what my problem was.  Thanks!

Comment: Should we do `cp ~/.config/flake8 ~/.config/flake8rc` ?

Answer (score 0):

`flake8` does not  have a plugin for `pylint`. It uses `pyflakes`:

```bash
→ flake8 --version
3.8.4 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.6.0, pyflakes: 2.2.0) CPython 3.8.6 on Linux
```

[There is currently no way to set the indent size in flake8 or pyflakes](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/-/merge_requests/167)

I have written a [`pylint` backend function](https://github.com/juergenhoetzel/flymake-pylint) for `flymake` function which may also meet your needs:

https://github.com/juergenhoetzel/flymake-pylint